# extjs 4 MVC Grid refresh (Chrome only)

Tags: google-chrome, grid, extjs4, refresh

I have a problem with `LiveSearchGridPanel` only in Chrome.I do simple `create/update` operation. It writes records to store and to database. But after saving `grid` does not refresh it's `view` and a can see new record only after reloading page. In Mozilla it is ok. I have tried `Ext.getCmp('myGridID').getStore().load();`

```
Ext.getCmp('myGridID').getView().refresh();
```

This is my controller code

```
    createOrder: function(button) {
    console.log('clicked the Save button Create');
    var win    = button.up('window'),
        form   = win.down('form'),
        record = form.getRecord(),
        values = form.getValues();


    console.log(values);
    this.getOrderStore().add(values);
    win.close();
    this.getOrderStore().sync();
    this.getOrderStore().load();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this.getOrderStore().add(values); be this.getOrderStore().add(record);  ?

Comment: What is it showing on the Chrome console? Its showing an error?

Comment: I'm sure it's showing an error in Chrome console. Otherwise it should work the same way as Firefox. How is your store configured?